# Getting a blue screen error even when I try to clean install windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Every time I try to install Windows 7, I always get a blue screen error 0x0000007E.

[image: http://picpaste.com/pics/a73a85f11d82c9b9ad4191a4bb131f00.1442408384.jpg]

Note that this error still occurs even after I format my hard drive and reinstall windows. This error has something to do with the wd.sys driver

Comment: Some tips: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/bsod-blue-screen-error/sys/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-2145/wd-sys/

Comment: None of those solutions apply to me

Comment: Can you please upload the image, using the provide function, then provide the urls to those images and somebody will inline for you.  You are going to have to give us more then the error code if you want help with this BSOD problem.

Comment: wd.sys = Microsoft Watchdog Timer Driver. analyze the dmp with Windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: For some reason this website is preventing me from uploading images

Comment: post links again. you need some reputation. I'll add it. You can post the output of Windbg on pastebin and add a link here

Comment: Have you tried different install media, maybe its corrupt.

Comment: Tried using a DVD and still got blue screen on restart